# Hide certain images on mobile devices

Tags: html

I'm trying to hide a image in my website for all the mobile devices. This is a html based website.
http://www.onefourbase.com/

I've tried few ways, but no help. Can you guys please help me to get it to the work?

```html
<div class="choseImg">
<img src="images/chose.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried media queries and hide image? Please mention what have you tried.
You can try below:

```
@media 
  only screen and (max-width: 767px)  {
    .choseImg{
       display:none;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to apply media queries to the images you want hidden on the mobile devices. One way to do that would be

```
@media screen and (max-width:your-value-here){
 img{display:none}
}
```

In place of 'your-value-here' type a width of a screen you want to place a breakpoint for your media queries in pixels. Also i suggest using classes or ids instead of 'img' tak to select the images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use media queries, the code in media queries is applied depending on some charactristics of the device :

```
@media mediatype and (expressions) {
CSS-Code;
}
```

In media type you can add screen to determine the size of the screen
In expression you precise the min-width: for which this applies

And in CSS-code you fill in the code that applies only if the screen is smaller than a number of pixels here display: none for the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using media queries.

First, add a class/id to the div that contains the images or to the image itself.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
.choseImg img{
display:none;
  }
}
```